# Is there a way to avoid global variable in this case?

Tags: javascript

I have a first function who has another function as parameter. And this function, creates a DOM element that must have onclick attribute with this parameter-function that comes from the first function! Just like this:

```
function funcOne(name,callback) {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
        button.setAttribute("id","myBtn");
        button.innerHTML = "Go to Func 2";
        button.setAttribute("onclick","funcTwo(this,'"+name+"','"+callback+"')");
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}

function funcTwo(element,name,callback) {
    let elementId = element.id;
    let yourName = name;
    console.log(yourName);
    callback();
}

funcOne('John',function(){alert('Holly cow!');});
```

The error, I believe, occurs in the "setAttribute" moment!
And the only solution I'm seeing is to set:

```
globalThis.myGlobalCallback= callback;
```

Inside the funcOne. So I can call "myGlobalCallback()" from funcTwo and dismiss the use of setAttribute data during the element creation! (Because I can set only ("onclick","myGlobalCallback()");
But this isn't the best way, it is?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the event listener using a JavaScript event listener instead of an HTML attribute, and you'll be able to reference the `name` inside the `funcOne` closure instead of making it (or the callback) global.

```
function funcOne(name, callback) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = 'myBtn';
    button.textContent = "Go to Func 2";
    button.addEventListener('click',() => {
        funcTwo(button, name, callback);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}

function funcTwo(element, name, callback) {
    const elementId = element.id;
    const yourName = name;
    console.log(yourName);
    callback();
}
```

Best practice is to never, ever use inline handlers (that is, `onclick="..."` in the HTML) - use `addEventListener` instead, and many of your scope problems (and tedious quoting issues) will go away.